# Can't create new activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia

Screenshot of the issue below:

[image]

I am using `vuforia` sample `videoplayback` android application. In that code, I cant create new activity. It shows like requires `minSdk >= 9`. Here I have attached the screenshot of the issue. Can anyone give me a solution.

Comment: where is attached screen shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `build.gradle` file, set `minsdkversion` as 9.

Comment: Thanks dude.. But I cant change the minSdkVersion value. When I try to change the value, I'm getting warning as "Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync may be necessary for the IDE to work properly. Please advise what can I do in this case

Comment: whenever you make changes to the build.gradle in your project you have to sync, so just click on the sync text.

Comment: i also would consider to set it a little bit higher (e.g. 15) because developing for android 2.3 is very outdated.

Answer (score 4):

Set `minSdkVersion` as 9 in your `build.gradle(Module: app)`.

Comment: Thanks dude.. But I cant change the minSdkVersion value. When I try to change the value, I'm getting warning as "Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync may be necessary for the IDE to work properly. Please advise what can I do in this case

Comment: sorry for late reply.As said above it is neccessary to sync the project whenever you make changes to build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

> when you change in the build gradle the sync is neccesary.try to rebuid and clean project.
>
> you can check the official documentation of min and max sdk using this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

When I upgrade Android Gradle to 7.3.0
and Gradle Version 7.5.1 .
so go to project structure -> project -> select gradle version